# Unable to dispatch Laravel event when Schedule runs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to fire an event called **ThriftStarted** everytime a schedule command is ran successfully. The event listener **GeneratePaymentSchedule** should handle the event and generate payment schedules. But it seems that I am missing something so when the schedule runs, no payment schedule is generated as intended.

Here's what my code looks like 
**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Thrift;
use App\Events\ThriftStarted;
...

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    ...

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // start thrift plan
        $schedule->call(function() {
            // get all open thrift plans
            $thrifts = Thrift::where('open', true)->get();

            // set open to false if contributors equals subscribers
            foreach ($thrifts as $thrift) {
                if ($thrift->contributors === $thrift->subscriptions->count()) {
                    $thrift->update(['open' => false]);

                    // dispatch thriftStarted event
                    event(new ThriftStarted($thrift));
                }
            }
        })->everyMinute();
    }

    ...
}
```

**ThriftStarted event**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Thrift;
...

class ThriftStarted
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Thrift $thrift)
    {
        $this->thrift = $thrift;
    }

    ...
}
```

**GeneratePaymentSchedule listener**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listener;

use App\Payment;
use App\Events\ThriftStarted;
...

class GeneratePaymentSchedule
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ThriftStarted  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ThriftStarted $event)
    {
        if ($event->thrift->open === 0) {
            $subs = Subscription::where('thrift_id', $event->thrift->id)->get();
            $schedule = Carbon::parse(now())->toDateString();

            foreach ($subs as $sub) {
                Payment::create([
                    'user_id'       => $sub->user_id,
                    'thrift_id'     => $sub->thrift_id,
                    'contribution'  => $sub->thrift->contribution,
                    'schedule'      => $schedule,
                ]);

                $schedule = Carbon::parse($schedule)->addMonth()->toDateString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EventServiceProvider**

```
<?php

...

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        App\Events\ThriftStarted::class => [
            App\Listener\GeneratePaymentSchedule::class,
        ]
    ];

    ...
}
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: How about some basic debugging. Are there errors in your log? Does the command get run properly? Does its `schedule()` method get run? Does the call to `event()` happen? If so, does the listener recognize it? Narrow down your question to the component that is causing problems and you might find yourself fixing your own problem in the process.

Comment: Have you declared `App\Events\ThriftStarted::$thrift` as a public property? It's not in the code you provided.

Comment: No errors in the log. The schedule runs successfully. I also declared `public $thrift`in the `ThriftStarted` event (will edit the code here). But the listener still doesn't handle it

Comment: Maybe you forget the scheduler. Add the cron job.  ```* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I'm still developing on my local system so it can't be the issue